# Is the following language in RE?

Tags: computability

There's a computability theory exercise that had me stuck for a long time. I have the language

```
L={ M | there exists a reduction from HP to L(M) }
```

I managed to prove it's not in R with a reduction from HP, but I can't figure out if it's in RE (or rather, I suspect it must not be in RE but can't prove it).

I'm not necessarily looking for an actual solution, but a clear enough hint, since it did elude me for a while now.

EDIT: M is a Turing machine. L(M)={x | M accepts x}. HP is the Halting Problem. RE is the Recursively Enumerable class of languages.

Comment: HP ? Halting problem ?

Comment: I do not know much about computability theory, but here is what I tried (assuming HP stands for the halting problem): if some language not in RE is many-one reducible to L, we are done.  What is a typical example of a language not in RE?  If I am not mistaken, this will give you an answer.

Comment: I believe posters should not use acronyms without defining them! And that includes RE, which not everyone will be familiar with. Also, I guess M a Turing machine and L(M) the language it accepts?

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: Homework or not, it's been posted now and other people are interested in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not in RE, you can show it by reduction from $\bar{HP}$. It's one of the common reductions (at least in the course i taught) but it's kind of tricky to figure out if you haven't seen it.

(added following the comments): consider the following reduction from $\bar{HP}$: $f(M,x)=M_{x}$ where $M_{x}$ acts in the following manner on an input w:

- run M on x for |w| steps
- if M stops then reject w
- else accept

if $(M,x)\in \bar{HP} $  then $L(M_{x})=\Sigma ^{*} $, if $(M,x)\notin \bar{HP} $  then $L(M_{x}) $ is finite and therefore in R.  This is still not sufficient to answer the original question, to do that you must refine the reduction a bit, so that instead of $\Sigma^{*}$ you get a language that HP is reducible to (for instance, HP itself).

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes please. I considered that but wasn't successful in figuring out one.

Comment: OK thanks I got the idea... Although I think you made a mistake in your conclusion of the reduction: if $(M,x)\in \bar{HP} $ then for every input w M will not halt on x and therefore we will reject, making the language of M_{x} an empty set. Or am I missing something?

Comment: there was a mistake in what i wrote, now corrected

Comment: The problem is that showing that $\bar{HP}$ reduces to a language $L$ does not prove that $L$ is not r.e. (indeed $L$ could be HP itself)

Answer (score 8):

One can solve this problem either by a direct proof or using an extended version of Rice's theorem (Theorem II.4.2 in Oddifredi's book *Classical Recursion Theory I*, where it is attributed to Myhill, Sheperdson, McNaughton and Shapiro). I'll start by the latter.

Rice's theorem says that given a property $P$ of languages:

- either $P$ is trivial (i.e. either all languages satisfy $P$, or none does)
- or the set $\mathcal{A}$ = {$M$ | $L(M)$ has the property $P$} is not computable

But here we want to know whether $\mathcal{A}$ can be recursively enumerable (the current trend is to say "computably enumerable" instead). This can happen: take for example: {$M$ | $M$ halts on at least 7 inputs}

The generalized version of Rice's theorem says the following. Given a property $P$ of languages, the set $\mathcal{A}$ = {$M$ | $L(M)$ has the property $P$} is computably enumerable if and only if there exists a computably enumerable set $F$ of finite sets of strings such that: $M \in L \Leftrightarrow (\exists u \text{ finite})~[u \in F  \text{  and  }  u \subseteq L(M)]$.

(Notice that it makes sense to talk about a computably enumerable set of *finite sets of strings*, as such objects can themselves be encoded by strings).

Here we have the set $\mathcal{A}$ = {$M$ | $HP$ reduces to $L(M)$}. Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is finite. Then there exists a computably enumerable set $F$ as above. Now

- If $F$ is non-empty and contains a finite set of strings $u$, then let $M_u$ be a Turing machine whose domain $L(M_u)$ is exactly $u$ (this is easy to build). Then by definition of $F$, $M_u \in \mathcal{A}$, but this means that $HP$ reduces to $L(M_u)=u$, which is a finite set (hence computable), a contradiction since $HP$ is not computable.
- Or $F$ is empty, in which case $\mathcal{A}$ is also empty, but this is not the case as there **does** exist a machine $M_{HP}$ whose domain is exactly $HP$ (as $HP$ is computably enumerable).

We have a contradiction!

But if you don't like using too powerful theorems we can do this directly, via an adaptation of Yohay's proof. Let $\mathcal{A}$ = {$M$ | $HP$ reduces to $L(M)$}. If $\mathcal{A}$ were computably enumerable, it would reduce to the halting problem $HP$. To show that this is not the case, we will show that some set **harder than $HP$** can be reduced to $\mathcal{A}$. We'll take the following: $INF$ = {$M$ | $L(M)$ is infinite}. The fact that $HP$ reduces to $INF$ but not vice-versa is standard (if you don't believe me, here is a nice and fairly easy exercise for you!).

Now we want to reduce $INF$ to $\mathcal{A}$. Let $M_{HP}$ be a fixed machine such that $L(M_{HP})=HP$. Let $M$ be any machine. Using $M$, construct the machine $M'$ which does the following.

For all input $x$, $M'$ counts the numbers of elements in $L(M)$. Whenever $n$ elements are found in $L(M)$, $M'$ runs the computation of $M_{HP}(x)$ during $n$ steps of computation. If this halts at any point, then $M'$ halts too, if not it waits to find more elements in $L(M)$ and repeats the process. There are two cases:

- If $M \notin INF$, then calling $k$ the number of elements of $L(M)$, by construction $M'$ will only emulate $M_{HP}$ during $k$ steps of computation for any input. For large inputs (|x|>k), this will be insufficient as $k$ steps won't even be enough to read the input! Hence $M'$ will not halt for all inputs $x$ such that $|x|>k$, hence $L(M')$ is finite, and hence $L(M') \notin HP$
- If $M \in INF$, then for any input $x$, $M'$ emulates $M_{HP}$ for infinitely many steps of computation, hence $L(M')=L(M_{HP})=HP$. And therefore $M' \in \mathcal{A}$.

We have proven $M \in INF \Leftrightarrow M' \in \mathcal{A}$, so $INF$ reduces to $\mathcal{A}$, which is what we wanted.